# Conventions for name mangling

Tags: c++

For a function say :

```
long myfunction(int,float)
```

the compiler may document this interface as, say :

```
?MyFunctionFoo@@YAXH
```

If I understand correctly, the additional characters decorating the original name **encodes** the number and types of parameters.

All that the standard says(1.3.17) about mangling is :

> Signatures are used as a basis for name mangling and linking.

Do compilers follow a standard convention for the *encoding scheme*  mentioned above?

Alternatively, are two compilers required to give identical *decorated name* for the same function?

Comment: In short: No, and no.

Comment: @NickyC you beat me with your answer because I was thinking what 5 more letters to add to "no and no" sentence ;)

Comment: No, C++ does not standardize an ABI. It is, however, something that has been deemed worth working on by some notable individuals.

Comment: @Logman I came up with `In short: `. ;)

Comment: @chris : I guess for obvious portability advantages..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do *all* compilers follow a single standard scheme?

No. Which answers your second question too.

Name mangling is a function of an ABI. And there are standard ABIs, which multiple compilers generate code for. The Itanium ABI, for example, [has its own name mangling scheme](https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling) that several compilers implement.

But the C++ standard gives no requirements for name mangling. Indeed, it doesn't even say that such name mangling is required.

Comment: Worth knowing what standard says about this.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that ABI stands for [\[ Application Binary Interface \]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface).

Comment: @NickyC : Yeah ! That's what I meant ;) See the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

> Do compilers follow a standard convention for the encoding scheme mentioned above?

No, there is no standard convention for the name mangling encoding scheme. Each compiler has its own name mangling scheme.

Some of them are described here [name mangling scheme](https://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf). Please go to the name mangling section in the document.